# Is the maximum size of a matching of graph equal to the maximum size of a matching of its dual?

Tags: graph-theory

This is really puzzling me!

A hypergraph $H = (V,E)$ consists of a set $V = \{v_1, v_2, \cdots, v_n\}$ of vertices and a set $E = \{e_1, e_2, \cdots , e_m\}$ of edges, each being a subset of $V$.

A subset $M \subseteq E(H)$ is a *matching* if every pair of edges from $M$ has an empty intersection.

The *dual* $H^*$ of $H$ is a hypergraph whose vertices and edges are interchanged, so that the vertices are given by $\{e_1, e_2, \cdots , e_m\}$ and whose edges are given by $X = \{X_1, X_2, \cdots, X_n\}$ where $X_j = \{e_j | v_j \in e_i \}$.

My question: Is the maximum size of a matching of $H$ equal to the maximum size of a matching of $H^*$?

Answer (score 1):

This is not the case. Consider the complete hypergraph on $n>1$ vertices, $H_n=(V,\mathcal{P}(V)\setminus\{\emptyset\})$.

Then the size of the maximum matching of $H_n$ is $n$, but every edge in the dual is incident with the vertex corresponding to the edge $V\in\mathcal{P}(V)\setminus\{\emptyset\}$, so any non-trivial matching in the dual has only one edge.